# activemq.base placeholder could not be resolved

Tags: java, jms, jetty, activemq-classic

I try to attach an activemq web console to my console app. Here goes my context.xml for the app:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
...
 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>activemq.properties</value>
    </property>
 </bean> 

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>file:${activemq.base}/conf/credentials.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
...

<import resource="${activemq.base}/conf/jetty.xml" />
...
```

where my activemq.properties file contains: 
    activemq.base=D:\development\apache-activemq-5.6.0

I keep getting an error, like "Could not resolve placeholder 'activemq.base'" , but it is actually written in the .properties file.

I have googled a ton of webpages and solutions and most of them tell, that activemq.base must be specified. Is there a mistake over here, that I don't see?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

tried to change config part to :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>activemq.properties</value>
            <value>file:${activemq.base}/conf/credentials.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

but still no change. Same stuff.